# Excel IF formula pulling text cell from multiple blank cells

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to use a formula that will take the cell in a row that contains text from multiple other blank cells.

```
      A      B       C
    1 Blank  Blank   Apple
    2 Blank  Orange  Blank
    3 Blank  Blank   Blank
```

I need the resulting column to fill: Apple, Orange, "blank"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your range is A1:C1, try this array formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:C1,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A1:C1),0))
```

It works, if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

And if you want to catch the error for the case, when there are only empty values, this is how to do it (again array formula):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:C1,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A1:C1),0)),"")
```

Comment: I adapted it for my spreadsheet: =IFERROR(INDEX(BZ2:CC2,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(BZ2:CC2),0)),"") but am getting a blank where there should be data in the outcome

Comment: @E.Weave. - the array formula is Ctrl+Shift+Enter, give it a try again.

Comment: Oh got it, I skipped the shift part, and had just done Ctrl+Enter. Looks like it's working now. Thank you!